# Get filename and path from uri for a text file

Tags: android, uri, text-files, absolute-path

I have an application that is supposed to be able to open and read a text file from an e-mail. 
I changed my manifest to the following

```
<activity 
android:name="FileLoaderActivity"
    android:label="@string/fileloader_title"
    android:parentActivityName="MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In my FileLoaderActivity I have the following inside the onCreate method:

```
// Get the intent that started this activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();

//Verify that the type is text file
if (intent.getType().equals("text/plain")) {
    String path = data.getPath();
    File file = new File(path);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), path,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if( file.exists())
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now the output is the following:

> /my_email@gmail.com/messages/78/attachments/0.1/BEST/false

and the "I exist" never shows up. Thus this won't open the file of course
I have read a lot of the other solutions but they seem to be Media specific. 
Can you please help me get the actual path to the file,

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you can just use

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

This isn't only just for images or media files. Of course the thing is you have to first download the file and then go into your download folder to open it. Also if you try to load a file, make sure you edit your Manifest to have the right permissions as follows:

```
<manifest> 
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for answers